# How to unwrap multidimensional array results in PyCharm console?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pycharm, word-wrap

I have python code which adds elements from 1 to 78 to list and then converts it to 3x26 matrix. I use PyCharm IDE and it wraps results after 24th element in each row. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
mylist=[]
for i in range(1,79):
    mylist.append(i)

data=np.matrix([mylist])
x=(data.reshape(3,26))
print(x)
```

And this is the result:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
  25 26]
 [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
  51 52]
 [53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76
  77 78]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What I want to do is to display each row in exactly one line (such as 25,26 and other two are not wrapped to a new line). How can I do that ? Is this problem pythonic or PyCharm related ? Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not PyCharm related. You will get exactly the same results in IDLE or the Python command-line interpreter.

Nor is it really Python related.

When your code calls `print(x)` you are asking for the string representation of `x`, which is a `numpy` matrix.

`numpy` does the conversion for you, and it is breaking the lines of output to fit nicely on a generic output console. It doesn't know you are using PyCharm.

A quick fix for this particular problem is to change `numpy`'s default output line length (which is 75).

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=90)
```

But to get full control over the output you will have to format the matrix yourself, rather than relying on the default string conversion that `numpy` provides.